# Getting npm ERR! code E429 Too many Requests Error when trying to publish a npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I just created a game on TypeScript/Node.js and tried to publish it on npm by first `npm login` and after that I used `npm publish` but after that it said:

```
error code E429
error 429 Too Many Requests - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/bombaclatt31-sadasd - Too Many Requests
```

I have tried many times and have also updated my npm version and Node version but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of `npm` are you using?

Comment: I'm using 10.5.0

Comment: After logging in, does your npm user name display when running `npm whoami`?